# Magnification of items during scrolling in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, uiscrollview, xamarin.forms, magnify

We need to implement a horizontal scroll control in Xamarin.Forms, that would not just allow scrolling through items via swipe, but would magnify elements in the row as they approach a center of the scroll control. The design of the layout desired is this:

[image]

Thus far I wasn't able to find any control for Xamarin or Xamarin.Forms that implements such behaviour.

Please either provide a hint on how to approach the implementation of such functionality via extending the UIScrollView, or point to a control or example that related to the requirement. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`CarouselView`](https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/), but it's still in the preview. So, the best way to implement it at the moment is to use the [CustomRenderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/)